# enable firefox pop ups in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, popup

I'm working on an Asp.Net application. I needed to open some hyperlinks in new tabs, I've already done that, but my companie's customers use firefox and have recently reported that firefox asks them for allowing pop up windows to open. Is there a code or way or something that I can enable firefox pop ups in my C# code? So that customers don't see the firefox question anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open links in a new tab, you won't use `window.open`.

Usually, the standard way of opening a link in a new window is using the `target="_blank"` attribute of the HTML Anchor element:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.es">Open Google</a>
```

Comment: the problem is not opening page in new tab, `I've already done that`, I just want to enable pop ups of firefox in code.

Comment: @mahditahsildari The problem, after all, is that this isn't possible. C# is a server language in case of using ASP.NET. C# wouldn't enable pop-ups in any Web browser.

Answer (score 1):

try opening windows using anchor tag..

```
<a href="1.htm" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">link text</a>
```

this another thread, but not tested, please try.. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=85806

Comment: the problem is not opening page in new tab, `I've already done that`, I just want to enable pop ups of firefox in code.